# How to edit schema.org markup of WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

How to edit schema.org markup of WooCommerce? Especially I am looking to delete the itemprop availability or hide it from Google rich snippets, but I cant find it in the woocommerce files.

[image]

I thought it´ll be within theme>woocommerce>single-product> ... But cant find it.

I am also happy with a hook via functions.php if you have any idea.

Answer (score 2):

to change or make your own schema look at `woocommerce/content-single-product.php`.
there are all hooks listed for a snippets in this file and I think you need a

```
WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data()
```

to replace